# Make full box-shadow support percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a jQuery plugin to allow you to apply a customizable preloader to your webpage. As a first release, I had an idea for this "futuristic circle" effect. The only issue is, the `box-shadow` property doesn't support percentage for the spread value. My css code for the plugin is available at https://github.com/tupperkion/preloader-plugin/blob/master/preloader.css. On line 27, you can see that I try to set the spread for `box-shadow` to `50%`. But Firefox just says `Error in parsing value for 'box-shadow'. Declaration dropped.`. I am wondering if I can use some sort of alternative method to support this without setting it to something like `9999999999px`, because that would screw up the animation that I plan on implementing at the end. The code is as follows:

```
.futuristic-circle-icon-inset-stage2 {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 50% white inset
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) ?

True, all dimensions must be `<length>` and not `<percentage>`.

Nevertheless you have a malformed property: `inset` must be the first token in it.

You can assign relative units to the dimensions, see [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length).